# is there a way to call a particular slide image in click event in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I did manage to get the previous image in the carousel on click but I'm not able to specify the "data-slide-to" image

This is the code for getting the previous image on click

```
$("#header").carousel('prev');
```

but while implementing the second one I'm getting no response

```
$("#header").carousel($(this).data('slide-to',0));
```

Comment: It depends entirely on the carousel plugin you're using and what methods it has

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function gotoSlide(number){
   $(".carousel").carousel(number);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="btn-1" onclick="gotoSlide(0);">1st Slide</button>
<button id="btn-2" onclick="gotoSlide(1);">2nd Slide</button>
<button id="btn-3" onclick="gotoSlide(2);">3rd Slide</button>


<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484151709479-3996843263cf?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459292414836-763d35c7ae4c?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506934535230-26f42bf91ae6?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1652&q=80" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An example using [Bootstrap 4's](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#methods)  Carousel methods

```
carousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {

  var active = $(event.target).find('.carousel-inner > .item.active');
  var from = active.index();
  var next = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var to = next.index();
  var direction = event.direction;

});
```

Comment: Thanks... but I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 :)